# Can generics be used to return the actual object?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this piece of code:

```
private object DeserialiseFromXMLFile(string fileLocation, Type type)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new
        XmlSerializer(type);

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open);
    XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
    return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

I'm wondering if I use generics because I'd like the return type to be T

Does anyone know if this is possible or is this the most elegant solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private T DeserialiseFromXMLFile<T>(string fileLocation)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new
        XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open);
    XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

You can then call it that way:

```
User item = DeserialiseFromXMLFile<User>("myFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
private T DeserialiseFromXMLFile<T>(string fileLocation)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new
        XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open);
    XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

The `typeof(T)` returns `Type` instance for the type `T` and in the end you explicitly cast the object returned by serializer to `T`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static T DeserialiseFromXMLFile<T>(string fileLocation)        {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open);
        XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);

        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
private T DeserialiseFromXMLFile<T>(string fileLocation)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new
        XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open);
    XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
    return (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Usage is then:

```
var foo = DeserialiseFromXMLFile<Foo>("Foo.xml");
```

If you don't like having to specify `Foo` explicitly, you could change the method to

```
private void DeserialiseFromXMLFile<T>(string fileLocation, out T t)
{
    ...
    t = (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

which you would call as

```
Foo foo;
DeserialiseFromXMLFile("Foo.xml", out foo);
```

---

Your code also could use a `using`:

```
private T DeserialiseFromXMLFile<T>(string fileLocation)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open))
    {
       var reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
       return (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```